# How can i make a SearchComponent Solr plugin distributed aware?

Tags: java, plugins, solr, distributed

i followed the instructions that i found [here](http://www.searchbox.com/developing-a-solr-plugin/) and [here](http://www.slideshare.net/searchbox-com/tutorial-on-developin-a-solr-search-component-plugin) to create my first Solr SearchComponentPlugin and everything went great for one core!

Now because i am using distributed search on multiple Shards(with same schema) i tried to test it on multiple cores without any success.

I found this [wiki](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/WritingDistributedSearchComponents) but i cant understand how can i make the DemoSearchComponent from searchbox to work with multiple cores similtaneous!

Does anyone got any good advice how to convert this demo component distributed aware?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By checking the code of an already Distributed aware Search Component, such as the Term Vector found it in org.apache.solr.handler.component, i manage to create my own distributed aware plugin.:)